# How to install Windows 7 in a machine running on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot

Recently I bought a laptop which is running in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Now I wants to move back to Windows 7 64 bit. Regarding same I created a boot-able USB and thinking to boot from USB. In new machine boot settings are not taking from USB and UBUNTU is getting loaded automatically , In boot setup I kept USB as primary option - Even though no luck . Any ideas how to remove UBUNTU completely and install windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only that your pc doesn't boot from usb, maybe you have to look for the "boot mode" option in bios... If you find it, you can try to switch from "uefi" to "legacy". If this doesn't work please send me your laptop model. Hope this can help.